# Is the feedback tag within our scope? Should it be?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, tagging, tag-synonyms

I just noticed the [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) tag on a question. It appears to be a recent addition added to 3 questions since it was created.

Shouldn't we discuss this?

I think there's a notable difference between [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) and [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback).

My far from perfect estimation of that difference is critique has an objective, which can *sometimes* lead to answers that have future value for other users. Whereas feedback, by it's very nature, is usually opinion-based and much more open to interpretation.

Am I incorrect? Are they the same thing?

What are the communities thoughts on whether [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) is in scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Ryan's answer (completely agree), I just created a **tag synonym** for **feedback = critique**.

With the new rep requirements after graduation, any user with more than **2500** reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag can suggest tag synonyms.

With a synonym, when someone inputs [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback), the system will automatically suggest [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique).

**Synonyms are not merges**, though. I'd suggest we merge these two (and leave [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique), unless we prefer the sound of "feedback"?).

If you feel we shouldn't merge, please leave an answer or comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that it will be problematic and leads to discussion and opinion.

I think it needs to be deleted. Currently it has no tag wiki definition so before it starts popping up more we should remove it.

Comment: Agreed. It gets automatically deleted if it doesn't get used in a while, but in the meantime we can create tag synonyms so when you use one you are actually using the other. Let's wait for some more feedback just in case, and if everyone agrees MERGE EM ALL!