# Feedback tag everywhere! Critique was so much better!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Per [this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/is-the-feedback-tag-within-our-scope-should-it-be) I thought we'd decided that feedback was not in scope. So we merged it with the [critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag. So now, for some reason, I'm seeing the [feedback](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) tag on lots of questions.

I thought it was established users *choosing* to add the feedback tag instead of critique, but now I've realised it seems to be automatically changing from critique.

Have we merged it the wrong way around?

Is there any way for us to obliterate that tag? Or have it always replaced by critique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had agreed on [replacing all feedback with critique](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1041/2857). Having both is redundant, we currently have the second as suggested when someone tries the first.

The mapping for the tag was incorrect, and was tagging critique as feedback instead of the other way around. This has been corrected, **please vote to approve the new synonym**: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/critique/synonyms